# Why do I get a blank return during this SQL query?

Tags: sql, database, ms-access

```
SELECT dependents.[Dependent_name], 
       "Child of " + employee.[Lname] + "," + employee.[Fname] AS Dependence
FROM dependents, employees AS employee
WHERE employee.[Lname] LIKE 'W%' 
  AND employee.Ssn = dependents.Essn 
  AND NOT dependents.Relationship = "Spouse"
ORDER BY employee.[Lname], dependents.[Dependent_name];
```

I'm attempting to create a query that will return a table with 2 fields. Those being dependent_name and Dependence. The only thing that is not properly functioning is the LIKE condition and I do not know why. It causes the whole table to not return anything. It should return 2 entries

Comment: [Bad habits to kick : using old-style JOINs](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-old-style-joins) - that old-style *comma-separated list of tables* style was replaced with the *proper* ANSI `JOIN` syntax in the ANSI-**92** SQL Standard (**25 years** ago) and its use is discouraged

Answer (score 2):

MS Access uses `*` as the wildcard in `LIKE`, not `%`.  So, try this `WHERE` condition:

```
WHERE employee.[Lname] LIKE 'W*' AND
      . . .
```